# How to replace a comma that connects the ArrayList elements by a dot or a column?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, replace, replaceall

Been trying to solve this thing for, probably, three hours, and didn't find the pleasing solution. Always was getting the 'Erroneous sym type' error or smth when using replaceAll() method.

So, here I have  a code snippet:

```
Hour_Sec[] Saving_Array = {
        new Hour_Sec(254, "Passengers are going to the KhPI"),
        new Hour_Sec(47, "Passengers are going to work"),
        new Hour_Sec(35, "Passengers are mainly students who are going home"),
        new Hour_Sec(59, "Passengers stopped working and went home")          
    };
LinkedList<Integer> Route_Numbers_Initializing = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Route_Numbers_Initializing.add(303);
    Route_Numbers_Initializing.add(220);
    Route_Numbers_Initializing.add(54);
    Route_Numbers_Initializing.add(707);
    Tramlines_Fst Station_Var = new Tramlines_Fst("Pushkinska", Route_Numbers_Initializing, Saving_Array);

    System.out.println(Station_Var.toString());
```

Which is, by itself, only a slice of a decent - for me - project. So, as you see, i print out some values needed, and then what I do is... overriding some function which results I use for the output:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Station Name is " + getStation_Name() + "\t" + "Route number: " + getRoute_Numbers() + "\t" + "Hour: " + Arrays.toString(Links_Array);
}
```

What I wanted is to replace all commas of the Saving_Array in my output by the columns to make it look better, so that I could add commas between the numbers and the comments instead (this step I'll do on my own in the second class, where such a thing lies):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getPassengers_Quantity() + " " + getComment();
}
```

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions. Variables should begin with lowercase, and underscores should be reserved for constants.

Comment: If you want others to be able to read and maintain your code, it's important to follow standards.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-

Comment: @Marvin I mean, the commas aren't included into my Array. I've to bust them out and the columns would take over the place.  They're just like connectors in the array of the another class fields.

Comment: Why get rid of commas if you are able to not include them in the first place? Try to play around with the method I linked.

Comment: @Marvin Grazie!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you wish to replace the commas with columns. a suggestion would be to add the commas when you print out the array list, because that would be the only time a user could see your array list.